# For Loop cannot work...I want to display data

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a program to decide what the user input is in the data file. How can I do this?

Code:

```
close all, clear all, clc;

%asking the user to input data
L=input('\Enter the value of length, L: ');

%load data file
load data.dat;
module=data(:,1);
l=data(:,2);

n=length(l);

for i=1:1:n
   if L==l(i);
       fprintf('\nLength = %.0f is found in the standard specification', l(i));
   else
       fprintf('\nLength = %.0f is NOT found in the standard specification', L);
   end
end
```

Data file:

```
1  300
2  591
3  752
4  801
5  1002
6  1200
7  1678
8  2190
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What does it do? Also, what language is this?

Comment: Matlab. The code does this: If I enter a value of 591, the program supposed to show Length = 591 is found in the standard specification.

Comment: If I enter a value of 600, the program is supposed to show Length=600 is NOT found in the standard specification.

Comment: @JackieNina Put this information in the question please. You cannot expect others to guess that...

Comment: What error do you get? Where do you get stuck in your debugging? Have you used `break points`?